# Pass variable sized input to Linear layer in Pytorch

Tags: computer-vision, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I have a `Linear()` layer in Pytorch after a few `Conv()` layers. All the images in my dataset are black and white. However most of the images in my test set are of a different dimension than the images in my training set. Apart from resizing the images themselves, is there any way to define the `Linear()` layer in such a way that it takes a variable input dimension? For example something similar to `view(-1)`

Comment: You have to pre-process your image array before passing in `torch.nn.Linear()` layer. I think there is no way to pass any external parameter as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it doesn't make sense to have a `Linear()` layer with a variable input size. Because in fact it's a learnable matrix of shape [n_in, n_out]. And matrix multiplication is not defined for inputs if theirs feature dimension != n_in

What you can do is to apply [pooling](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.functional.html#avg-pool1d) from functional API. You'll need to specify `kernel_size` and `stride` such that resulting output will have feature dimension size = n_in.